# In Codeingiter db active dbprefix don't apply in concat(), sum() methods

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I am using codeigniter 2.2.4

I have to use table prefixes for backups every year i.e 2017_

It does n't work in complex select queries like

```
$this->db->select('concat(users.firstname, " ", users.lastname) AS name users.email', FALSE);
$this->db->get('users');

echo $this->db->last_query();
die();
```

The above code returns this query

```
SELECT concat(users.firstname, ' ', 2017_users.lastname) AS name, 2017_users.email FROM (`2017_users`)
```

I want to know if there is any other way to use concat(), sum() in codeigniter DB active record so that it can apply db_prefixes

I want this result when I set codeigniter dbprefix to 2017_

```
SELECT concat(2017_users.firstname, ' ', 2017_users.lastname) AS name, 2017_users.email FROM (`2017_users`)
```

Also add prefix in table names that comes in sql functions i.e concat(), sum()

Comment: What your exact expectation that you want?

Comment: @Sadikhasan i think,  the promlem that prefix is not added at `concat(users.firstname,`

Comment: Yes, I also add the resultant query I want from this.

Comment: In my opinion, get values separately first and assign to variable and then apply the concate function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append `prefix` by `$this->db->dbprefix`. change your code to:

```
$this->db->select("concat({$this->db->dbprefix}users.firstname, ' ', 
{$this->db->dbprefix}users.lastname) AS name, users.email", FALSE);
$this->db->get('users');

echo $this->db->last_query();
die();
```

Comment: Why you use {} parenthesis around $this->db->dbprefix, what does they do I have never seen before???

Comment: It works this way But I have to change in whole project :( thnaks.

Comment: It  will execute variable of object/array which is in quotation